# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' in flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Every time I try tp post the form, i run into the same error in the flask app

```
h, actual_method = _hash_internal(method, salt, password)
 password = password.encode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

here is the html

```
<form id="signupForm">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="tel" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
            <select name="account_type" required>
                <option value="">Account Type</option>
                <option value="Tutor">Tutor</option>
                <option value="student">Student</option>
            </select>

            <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

and the python code

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.form.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.form.get('last_name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        phone_number = request.form.get('phone_number')
        account_type = request.form.get('account_type')

        #check if theres already an account using the provided email
        exist = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if exist:
            flash("Email already exists")
            return redirect('/login')

        # Hash the password before storing it in the database
        print(password)
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)

        # Create a new User object
        user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email,
                    password=hashed_password, phone_number=phone_number, account_type=account_type)

        # Add the user to the database
        add_user(user)

        return redirect('/login')

    return render_template('html/signup.html')
```

The pyhton code runs perfectly when i test it by sendind a post request with data in a dict form, but when i enter data in the form, it shows theres a problem with the password = generate_passsword_hash(password). I have tried to cross check the spelling to see whether the python and the html form names are the same for different attributes and it seemed theres no error in that